# tangent line, equation

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Can you prove which is the tangent equation using derivative.

Why the tangent line $l$ through $(x_{0}, f(x_{0}))$ with slope $f'(x_{0})$ is:
$$l(x)=f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})(x-x_{0}) \mbox{?}$$

Thank!

Answer (score 3):

The equation of any line passing through  $(x_{0}, f(x_{0}))$  is $\frac{y-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=m$  where $m$ is the slope.

Now if the line is a tangent of $y=f(x)$ at $(x_{0}, f(x_{0}))$, the slope of the line = the slope of  $y=f(x)$ at $(x_{0}, f(x_{0}))$ which is  $f'(x_{0})$ .

So, the equation of the line which is  a tangent of  $y=f(x)$  at $(x_{0}, f(x_{0}))$ will be $\frac{y-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=f'(x_0)$

Comment: Ok :) now, how can I do the transition to the tangent plan. 

$\displaystyle z=f(x_{0},y_{0})+[\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_{0},y_{0})](x-x_{0})+[\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_{0},y_{0})](y-y_{0})$

Comment: Let $t = (x,y).$ Then, $z = f(t_0)+\nabla(t_0)(t-t_0)$ which is the $\mathbb{R}^2$ generalization of the $\mathbb{R}$ example first considered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**  What is the equation of a line through a point with a given slope?